# Display tag : The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, displaytag

This is working fine in my machine. But when I deployed it to a different one the following exception is thrown. Both computers run Tomcat 6.0 and the required jar file is in place.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Does anyone have any idea about what I am missing?

Comment: have you checked the version of displaytag .jar file? maybe it's wrong or too old

Answer (score -1):

That message is caused when no appropriate TLD file is found. You are either missing a JAR (or you have the wrong version of it) or a TLD declaration in web.xml.

Recheck your setup.

Consult the appropriate documentation for your library version:

http://www.displaytag.org/10/install.html

 http://www.displaytag.org/10/tlds.html

http://www.displaytag.org/11/install.html

 http://www.displaytag.org/11/tlds.html

http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/install.html

 http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tlds.html

Comment: I have the exact same setup in both the machines. They are oth created from the same Maven pom file. And i double checked to make sure the jar files are in place.