# http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jsp-tags

While trying to load from the database, I am getting the following errors in eclipse.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files
```

Complete stack trace here:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:316)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1397)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please find the web.xml here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringAndHibernate</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And View page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
<html>
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<a href="indexpage.htm">Click here for Home</a>

<h2 align="center">View Information</h2>
<body></body><center>
<display:table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="20" id="employee" name="employee" pagesize="10"
    export="false" requestURI="displayEmployee.htm">
    <display:column property="emp_id" title="Employee Id" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="name" title="Employee Name"
        href="editdata.htm" paramId="id" paramProperty="emp_id"
        sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="address" title="Address" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="salary" title="Salary" sortable="true" />
    <display:column value="Delete" href="deletedata.htm" paramId="id"
        paramProperty="emp_id" title="Delete" sortable="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
</display:table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to declare for `<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>` with web.xml?

I have gone via
[Display tag : The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122944/display-tag-the-absolute-uri-http-displaytag-sf-net-cannot-be) 
but not resolved.

Comment: Are you sure the displaytag jar really is in your classpath?

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld: I am sorry, It was missing.... added  displaytag-1.2.jar .. And working now. Will accept once you post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the displaytag jar is in your classpath!

Answer (score 0):

After adding it to the class path got the same error 
Still we go the error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

When we add it to the Deployment Assembly error got resolved